# Proof: $\mathbb{Z}_n$ has zero divisors if and only if $n$ is not prime.

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-writing, proof-explanation

I know this has to be proven both ways since it is an if and only if question, but I do not know how to go about this or even where to start either side of the proof. I know $[a][b]=[0]$ for there to be a zero divisor. Please help!

Comment: If $n$ is not prime, then $n=ab\ldots$

Answer (score 3):

$n$ is not prime $\iff n=ab, 1\lt a,b\lt n\iff ab\cong0\pmod n\iff a$ and $b$ are zero divisors.

Comment: It would be good to be a little more specific when you write $n = ab$; you also want both $a$ and $b$ to not be equal to $n$.

Comment: You're right.   I have edited.   @QiaochuYuan